# How to get long,lat for all IP addr in the JSON nested array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, nested, geolocation

need help in fixing php code, wanted to get longitude and latitude for all IP addresses in the JSON array and either dump their geo location data in .csv file or display them in  JSON again.

**Sample JSON array:**

```
[
  {
    "addr": "103.229.122.253:19667",
    "services": 1,
    "lastsend": 1578797285,
    "lastrecv": 1578797285,
    "conntime": 1577841460,
  },
  {
    "addr": "212.239.222.147:19667",
    "services": 1,
    "lastsend": 1578797395,
    "lastrecv": 1578797395,
    "conntime": 1577841462,
  },
  {
    "addr": "[2602:ffc5:20::1:63b5]:19667",
    "services": 1,
    "lastsend": 1578797381,
    "lastrecv": 1578797381,
    "conntime": 1577936686,
    "banscore": 0
  }
]
```

**PHP code:**

```
<?php

ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);

// Read JSON file
$readjson = file_get_contents('*extenal link to get JSON data*') ;

//Decode JSON
$data = json_decode($readjson, true);

foreach ($data as $emp) {
echo  $emp['addr'] .",";
}
echo "<br/>";

?>
```

Comment: Nice tutorial might help https://zatackcoder.com/convert-ip-address-location-php/

Comment: array_column ? Why don't use for get addr?